# I have error in run react-native for ios on macbook

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

when started code: `react-native run-ios`

after run Simulator
error showing: `error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening appone.xcodeproj`

tnx for fix my problem.